# Is it better to list adjectives, with an "and"?

Tags: adjectives, punctuation, lists, compound-adjectives

When we use more than one adjective, e.g.

> The big, red, bouncy balloon.

The list of three adjectives {big, red, and bouncy} is a list, so by rights it should be separated by commas, with an "and" between the last two terms.

If somebody asked us to describe the balloon we would without hesitation say that it is "big, red **and** bouncy".  Going by the rules, the correct form for the first phrase given above would be to write:

> The big, red and bouncy balloon.

But we virtually never see this.  In lists of adjectives *and* is used as the exception, whereas in lists in general, to exclude it is the exception. Is it a correct technicality to include the "and", which nobody observes, thereby making it acceptable to exclude the "and" on the basis of common usage?  And to write the best English we can, should we be including the "and" in lists of adjectives?

Comment: Why do you think that rules that apply to nouns and verbs also apply to adjectives and adverbs? There's no rule that says you need to use *and* for a list of adjectives that come right before the noun.

Comment: "Going by the rules" - what "rules"? But you can use "and" in a list of adjectives modifying a noun. Particularly if you want to emphasise the last one - in your 2nd example, you are letting us know that the ball is *bouncy* as well as being big and red.

Comment: @bookmanu I think that's a related but different instance, as in that example it's a device used as an exception whereas in this case it's the norm.

Comment: @PeterShor this rule applies to nouns, verbs *and adjectives*, as in the example I gave: *is "big, red and bouncy".*  - in fact it's the standard rule for any list.

Comment: In your example, it’s a matter of style whether you join them with an *and*. You’d consider factors such as where you want to place the emphasis to bring out your intent.

Comment: @RobertFrost Perhaps because of the verb to be, cf. The balloon **is** big, red and bouncy vs The balloon **is** big, red, bouncy (the second sentence doesn't sound right) and The big, red, bouncy balloon is about to pop vs The big, red, and bouncy balloon is about to pop - both are correct but "and" in the second sentence emphasises the bounciness?

Comment: @RobertFrost: Can you find a reference that says you must join attributive adjectives coming directly before the noun with an *and*? I suspect not. There is no such rule in English, and I don't believe there ever has been—at least, not for the last 400 years. If the adjectives are not directly before the noun, you indeed do need to join them with an *and*.

Comment: I suspect not as well, provided we exclude from our list of references those which speak only of lists in general.

Comment: In [Spanish](http://www.spanishdict.com/answers/211493/what-sort-of-syntax-do-you-use-when-using-more-than-2-adjectives), you do indeed usually need to put an *y* between the last two adjectives in a list. But in English, there is no such rule for adjectives before the noun and there hasn't been one for the last four centuries. Ditto for adverbs.

Comment: It was the question of whether there should be a comma after the last adjective, which drew my attention to the practice of excluding the "and". By that point I had been excluding the "and" for forty years without before noticing that it was inconsistent with the handling of lists in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, it's not necessary.  But that's a style thing; what you've written isn't wrong.

To me, the way you have written it emphasises the bounciness over all the other adjectives by separating it out from the others.  It's also noticeable, because it doesn't follow the conventional order of adjectives - see [Cambridge Dictionary adjectives order](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/about-adjectives-and-adverbs/adjectives-order).

A more common ordering would be "the big, bouncy, red balloon".

Comment: Why would you not have a comma between "bouncy" and "red"?

Comment: @RobertFrost I was being inconsistent.  It looks like it's normal to add commas for 3 or more adjectives, so I have fixed it above.

Comment: It was actually the question of whether there should be a comma after the last adjective, which drew my attention to the practice of excluding the "and". By that point I had been excluding the "and" for forty years without ever noticing!

Comment: @RobertFrost Personally I wouldn't, and the Cambridge Dictionary doesn't on their web site.  But then, I have always commas in based on where I would pause when speaking, rather than using any fancy rule.